# List of existentially quantified values in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, higher-rank-types

I'm wondering why this piece of code doesn't type-check:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, Rank2Types, RankNTypes #-}
{-# OPTIONS -fglasgow-exts #-}

module Main where

foo :: [forall a. a]
foo = [1]
```

ghc complains:

```
Could not deduce (Num a) from the context ()
  arising from the literal `1' at exist5.hs:7:7
```

Given that:

```
Prelude> :t 1
1 :: (Num t) => t
Prelude>
```

it seems that the (Num t) context can't match the () context of arg. The point I can't understand is that since () is more general than (Num t), the latter should and inclusion of the former. Has this anything to do with lack of Haskell support for sub-typing?

Thank you for any comment on this.

Comment: For what I know, t is a subtype of s if any function f taking an argument of type s, can also take an argumento of type t.

Comment: Something like `class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a` and then `(\x -> if x == 0 then "zero" else show x) :: Num a => a -> String`? i.e. one class  requires another classes also (functions `(==)` and `show` takes values of `Eq a` and `Show a` respectively and v`Num a` is their "subtype" and values of that class can be passed to that functions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not using existential quantification here. You're using rank N types.

Here `[forall a. a]` means that every element must have every possible type (not any, every). So `[undefined, undefined]` would be a valid list of that type and that's basically it.

To expand on that a bit: if a list has type `[forall a. a]` that means that all the elements have type `forall a. a`. That means that any function that takes any kind of argument, can take an element of that list as argument. This is no longer true if you put in an element which has a more specific type than `forall a. a`, so you can't.

To get a list which can contain any type, you need to define your own list type with existential quantification. Like so:

```
data MyList = Nil | forall a. Cons a MyList
foo :: MyList
foo = Cons 1 Nil
```

Of course unless you restrain element types to at least instantiate `Show`, you can't do anything with a list of that type.

Comment: I have to elaborate on this. Anyway, it seems that in Haskell you can't directly specify an existential types, but you can do that indirectly using data types, i.e. what you did in the MyList example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, your example doesn't even get that far with me for the current GHC, because you need to enable `ImpredecativeTypes` as well. Doing so results in a warning that ImpredicativeTypes will be simplified or removed in the next GHC. So we're not in good territory here. Nonetheless, adding the proper Num constraint (`foo :: [forall a. Num a => a]`) does allow your example to compile.

Let's leave aside impredicative types and look at a simpler example:

```
data Foo = Foo (forall a. a)
foo = Foo 1
```

This also doesn't compile with the error `Could not deduce (Num a) from the context ()`.

Why? Well, the type promises that you're going to give the Foo constructor something with the quality that for any type `a`, it produces an `a`. The only thing that satisfies this is bottom. An integer literal, on the other hand, promises that for any type `a` *that is of class Num* it produces an `a`. So the types are clearly incompatible. We can however pull the forall a bit further out, to get what you probably want:

```
data Foo = forall a. Foo a
foo = Foo 1
```

So that compiles. But what can we do with it? Well, let's try to define an extractor function:

```
unFoo (Foo x) = x
```

Oops! `Quantified type variable 'a' escapes`. So we can define that, but we can't do much interesting with it. If we gave a class context, then we could at least use some of the class functions on it.

There is a time and place for existentials, including ones without class context, but its fairly rare, especially when you're getting started. When you do end up using them, often it will be in the context of GADTs, which are a superset of existential types, but in which the way that existentials arise feels quite natural.

Comment: Truth. Using existential types without classes which provides operations over them is meaningless. You can't apply anything to value with fully undefined type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About the absence of type context, that's fine because it's toy code and I wanted just to strees the existential type point.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you can create something like `forall a. (a, a -> Integer, Integer -> a)` so that functions shipped with value will allow you to do some manipulations.

Comment: Is this possible: `[1::Int, 2::Integer] :: forall a. Num a => [a]` with ExistentialQuantification? If not, why not? Is this due to the definition of `[]` thus necessitating your own existentially enabled `MyList`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai no that doesn't make sense. The forall being outside the list means that the _same_ `a` needs to be able to be picked for any element of the list, and that `a` needs to be picked _at the use site_ -- i.e. anyone using the list can instantiate that to any `a` subject to `Num` that they desire. That's clearly not what the term provides.

Comment: I realised I needed to read up more about about rank-n polymorphism and impredicative polymorphism, since I keep getting confused about the fundamental difference between `[forall a. Num a => a]` and `forall a. Num a => [a]` and their respective uses in term signatures and function signatures. I found this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/boxy/impredicative.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Because the declaration `[forall a. a]` is (in meaning) the equivalent of saying, "I have a list, and if you (i.e. the computer) pick a type, I **guarantee** that the elements of said list will be that type."

The compiler is "calling your bluff", so-to-speak, by complaining, "I 'know' that if you give me a `1`, that its type is in the `Num` class, but you said that I could pick any type I wanted to for that list."

Basically, you're trying to use the value of a universal type as if it were the type of a universal value. Those aren't the same thing, though.