# Constraining the return type to a Context

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Here are my attempts so far:

```
module Main where

data FooT = One | Two deriving (Show, Read)
{-
That is what I want
foo :: (Show a, Read a) => a
foo = One
-}

--class Footable (Show a, Read a) => a where
class Footable a where
  --foo2 :: (Show a, Read a) => a
  foo2 :: a

instance Footable FooT where
  foo2 = One

-- test = print foo2
```

I want test to compile. I don't think the problem revolves around universal quantification. ghc says that a is a 'strict type-variable' **edit** (*rigid* type variable) but I don't really comprehend what this is. The question seems to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149975?tab=votes#tab-top)

**Edit**

As I wrote in my comment @sepp2k it's probably about the existential type but I have stumbled over a curious behaviour:

This *does* compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances,
UndecidableInstances, MonomorphismRestriction, PolymorphicComponents #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-monomorphism-restriction #-}

module Main where

    class (Num a) => Numable a where
      foo2 :: a

    instance (Num a) => Numable a where
      foo2 = 1

    instance Numable Int where
      foo2 = 2

    instance Numable Integer where
      foo2 = 3

    --test = foo2 + foo2 -- This does NOT compile (ambiguous a) 
    test = (foo2::Integer) + foo2 --this works
```

but this does not (`a' is a rigid type variable message)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances,
UndecidableInstances, MonomorphismRestriction, PolymorphicComponents #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-monomorphism-restriction #-}

module Main where

    data FooT = One | Two deriving (Show, Read)
    data BarT = Ten deriving (Show, Read)

    class (Show a, Read a) => Footable a where
      foo2 :: a

    instance (Show a, Read a) => Footable a where
      foo2 = Ten

    instance Footable FooT where
      foo2 = One

    main = print foo2
```

that's so because 1 :: (Num t) => t. Can I define something (typeconstructor, consts dunno) like that?

Comment: Backticks don't work to format multiple lines of code. You have to indent by four spaces (or use the code button or Ctrl-K).

Comment: and apostrophes mess with the color scheme. But now it is fine.

Comment: You should really start posting whole error messages. The important part of the message is "Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `BarT", not "a is a rigid type variable..." (which does not describe the error - it only tells you where a comes from).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I uncomment the definition of `test` and try to compile your code, I get "ambiguous type variable". Nothing about strictness. To understand why this is ambiguous consider this:

```
module Main where

data FooT = One | Two deriving (Show, Read)
data BarT = Three | Four deriving Show

class Footable a where
  foo2 :: a

instance Footable FooT where
  foo2 = One

instance Footable BarT where
  foo2 = Three

main = print foo2  -- Should this print One or Three?
```

Of course in your code there is only one instance of Footable, so haskell could in theory infer that you want to use the `foo2` defined for `FooT` because that's the only instance in scope. However if it did that, the code would break as soon as you import a module that happens to define another instance of Footable, so haskell doesn't do that.

To fix your problem you need to annotate foo2 with its type like so:

```
module Main where

data FooT = One | Two deriving (Show, Read)

class Footable a where
  foo2 :: a

instance Footable FooT where
  foo2 = One

main = print (foo2 :: FooT)
```

To require that all Footables be instances of Show and Read simply do:

```
class (Show a, Read a) => Footable a where
  foo2 :: a
```

Like you did in your comments, but without specifying the constraint again in the signature of foo2.

Comment: my idea was that if I constrain foo in that way foo :: (Show a, Read a) => a I could return various types without violating type-safety. (the 'strict type-variable' pops up when you uncomment the function foo). My class Footable was an attempt to solve problem. What I need are existential type or type-families.

Comment: When you do `main = print 3` it will specialize `3` to `Integer` type (even that the only required is `(Num a, Show a)`). Probably there is some way to define "defaults"

Comment: @ony: There is no way to define defaults for user-defined typeclasses.

Answer (score 2):

As sepp2k said, Ghc can't guess the return type of foo2. Do constraint it (which is the title of your question) add an inline type signature.

> test = print (foo2 :: FooT)

Comment: ::FooT does not constrain to a context, but declares foo2 to be of the type FooT

Comment: which is what we want, don't we ?